# after update trigger causes unexpected exception

Tags: trigger

I have two custom objects:

`Contract__c` and `Address__c`.

`Address__c` has a `value__c` currency field on it.

`Contract__c` has a rollup summary field, which holds the maximum value of the attached addresses. The field name is: `max_value__c`.
`Contract__c` also has another field called `est_loss__c` and a field called 'limit__c`.

So, I need to do the following:

I need to update the `limit__c` field on `Contract__c` based on the rollup field and the other currency field.  I do this in my trigger as follows:

```
trigger ContractTrigger on Contract__c (after update) {

    for (Contract__c con : Trigger.new){

            if(con.est_limit__c < con.max_value__c){
                con.limit__c = con.est_limit__c;
            }
            if(con.est_limit__c >= con.max_value__c){
                con.limit__c = con.max_value__c;
            }
        }
        update(con);

}
```

All this looks pretty simple, but when I try this, it all fails. So, I can create a contract, and then I want to add an address. When I try to save the address, I get the following error:

```
 Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger ContractTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContractTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.ContractTrigger
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? As far as I know I don't have read-only fields... Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an `after update` trigger and trying to update the records send to you via Trigger.new.  Please see this page to see what actions are available in each type of trigger: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

In general, when you are attempting to update the record you are writing the trigger on you use `before` and when you want to create or edit a different record you use `after`.

Changing your trigger to a `before update` trigger should work find barring any other errors.

Comment: And, of course, removing the dml update statement.

Comment: Hello, no, the trigger does not work when I use a before update unfortunately. I then get the following error message: `Apex trigger ContractTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContractTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statment cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old: Trigger.ContractTrigger: ` Here it is referring to the line with the update(con); statement.

Comment: @Lily sfdcfox is correct.  you must remove the DML statement.  A before trigger doesn't require an update statement.